# ¿Cómo reducir correctamente alto del input type="file" de bootstrap 4.4?

Tags: javascript, html, css

*No tengo conocimiento en como reducir el alto del input type="file" que tiene bootstrap 4.4 he buscado en su documentación y no logre encontrar solución. Estoy desarrollando un sistema basado en esa versión de bootstrap.*

**CSS** **Y** **HTML:**

```css
.reducir label {
  height: 30px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.reducir input[type=file] {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <title>Hello, world!</title>
  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container-fluid px-4 py-4">
    <h4>Reducir alto del input type="file"</h4>

    <!--Uso de la clase "reducir"-->
    <div class="reducir">
      <div class="custom-file w-75">
        <input type="file" class="custom-file-input" id="customFileLang" lang="es">
        <label class="custom-file-label" for="customFileLang">Seleccionar Archivo</label>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

  <footer>
    <!-- Bootstrap JS-->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </script>
  </footer>

</body>

</html>
```

> Al momento de llamar a la clase "reducir" no lo reduce el alto del input como deseo.

Comment: Checa su documentación, viene un apartado sobre el tamaño https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/forms/#sizing

Comment: ya lo revise con anterioridad pero no encontré  una clase que reduzca al input de **type=file**.

Comment: Por favor dale clic al enlace que te mandé, aplica para cualquier tipo de input, otra manera es que lo hagas con CSS, si no te deja, pones la propiedad como important

Comment: Muchas gracias.